# unable to alert offerid using json object

Tags: php, json

I am trying to alert offerId but unable to print it tried with json stringify and json.parse but not working, offer id under products should be printed in alert please suggest, if i can alert offerId then problem will get solved.

```
{
"result": {
    "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponse",
    "entries": [
        {
            "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry",
            "batchId": 0,
            "product": {
                "kind": "content#product",
                "id": "online:en:IN:15783",
                "offerId": "15783",
                "contentLanguage": "en",
                "targetCountry": "IN",
                "channel": "online"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry",
            "batchId": 1,
            "product": {
                "kind": "content#product",
                "id": "online:en:IN:15831",
                "offerId": "15831",
                "contentLanguage": "en",
                "targetCountry": "IN",
                "channel": "online"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry",
            "batchId": 2,
            "product": {
                "kind": "content#product",
                "id": "online:en:IN:15846",
                "offerId": "15846",
                "contentLanguage": "en",
                "targetCountry": "IN",
                "channel": "online"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"body": "{\n  \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponse\",\n  \"entries\": [\n    {\n      \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry\",\n      \"batchId\": 0,\n      \"product\": {\n        \"kind\": \"content#product\",\n        \"id\": \"online:en:IN:15783\",\n        \"offerId\": \"15783\",\n        \"contentLanguage\": \"en\",\n        \"targetCountry\": \"IN\",\n        \"channel\": \"online\"\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry\",\n      \"batchId\": 1,\n      \"product\": {\n        \"kind\": \"content#product\",\n        \"id\": \"online:en:IN:15831\",\n        \"offerId\": \"15831\",\n        \"contentLanguage\": \"en\",\n        \"targetCountry\": \"IN\",\n        \"channel\": \"online\"\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry\",\n      \"batchId\": 2,\n      \"product\": {\n        \"kind\": \"content#product\",\n        \"id\": \"online:en:IN:15846\",\n        \"offerId\": \"15846\",\n        \"contentLanguage\": \"en\",\n        \"targetCountry\": \"IN\",\n        \"channel\": \"online\"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}\n",
"headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-length": "231",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Wed, 04 May 2022 09:52:42 GMT",
    "server": "ESF",
    "vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer"
},
"status": 200,
"statusText": null }
```

Javascript code

```
function execute() {

return gapi.client.content.products.custombatch(<?php echo json_encode($product_data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>).then(function(response) 
{  //not working    alert(response.result[2]);  //alert response.status is working alert(response.status);   });
```

Comment: Is that JSON you have shown us supposed to be the content of `$product_data`, or the `response` you got?

Comment: i am getting this in response

Comment: Then what is `response.result[2]` supposed to access? `result` is not a numerically indexed array (or an object that had a property named `2`.) Do you want to access the third of the `entries` maybe ...?

Comment: alert(response.result[2]);  don't work

Comment: response.status  is working   output  = 200

Comment: _"don't work"_ - of course not, and did I not _just_ explain why ...?

Comment: Please suggest how i can alert offerId   thanks for your help

Comment: Well you need to access one of the `entries` below `response.result` first, then the `product` inside that, and then the `offerId` of that product ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//Please Try This

  var data =  {
"result": {
    "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponse",
    "entries": [
        {
            "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry",
            "batchId": 0,
            "product": {
                "kind": "content#product",
                "id": "online:en:IN:15783",
                "offerId": "15783",
                "contentLanguage": "en",
                "targetCountry": "IN",
                "channel": "online"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry",
            "batchId": 1,
            "product": {
                "kind": "content#product",
                "id": "online:en:IN:15831",
                "offerId": "15831",
                "contentLanguage": "en",
                "targetCountry": "IN",
                "channel": "online"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry",
            "batchId": 2,
            "product": {
                "kind": "content#product",
                "id": "online:en:IN:15846",
                "offerId": "15846",
                "contentLanguage": "en",
                "targetCountry": "IN",
                "channel": "online"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"body": "{\n  \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponse\",\n  \"entries\": [\n    {\n      \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry\",\n      \"batchId\": 0,\n      \"product\": {\n        \"kind\": \"content#product\",\n        \"id\": \"online:en:IN:15783\",\n        \"offerId\": \"15783\",\n        \"contentLanguage\": \"en\",\n        \"targetCountry\": \"IN\",\n        \"channel\": \"online\"\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry\",\n      \"batchId\": 1,\n      \"product\": {\n        \"kind\": \"content#product\",\n        \"id\": \"online:en:IN:15831\",\n        \"offerId\": \"15831\",\n        \"contentLanguage\": \"en\",\n        \"targetCountry\": \"IN\",\n        \"channel\": \"online\"\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"kind\": \"content#productsCustomBatchResponseEntry\",\n      \"batchId\": 2,\n      \"product\": {\n        \"kind\": \"content#product\",\n        \"id\": \"online:en:IN:15846\",\n        \"offerId\": \"15846\",\n        \"contentLanguage\": \"en\",\n        \"targetCountry\": \"IN\",\n        \"channel\": \"online\"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}\n",
"headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-length": "231",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Wed, 04 May 2022 09:52:42 GMT",
    "server": "ESF",
    "vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer"
},
"status": 200,
"statusText": null }

data.result.entries.map(myFunction);
function myFunction(num) {
 alert(num.product.offerId);
}
```